# Sails: Accessing native mongodb-driver

Tags: sails.js

I want to make a few db-commands on startup at sails. Like: db.dropDatabase(), db.repairDatabase(), ...

I know you can use

```
mymodel.native()
```

For link to db.collection("mymodel")

But how i can access the database-object directly?

Comment: We don't currently expose the db object only the collection object from the `native` command. You could patch the adapter to add it though by looking into the `native` function here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/master/lib/adapter.js#L212-L217

Comment: Did you find a solution better than using directly the mongo driver?

Answer (score 1):

I added in the adapter.js the following:

```
getDB: function(connectionName, collectionName, cb) {
      var connectionObject = connections[connectionName];
      cb(null, connectionObject.connection.db);
    },
```

And used it as Model.getDB():

```
User.getDB(function (err,db){
        console.log('getDB');

        var collection = db.collection('test');
        // Insert some documents
        collection.insert([ {a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}], function(err, result) {
            console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the document collection", result);
        });

        return res.json({
          notice: 'Inserted 3 documents into the document collection'
        });

      });
    }
```

Comment: instead of added directly in node_modules, Cant we extend the same in Config/adapter.js ... Any one have idea on how to do this.